# Google charts column chart ignoring 0 values for annotation positioning

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

The issue that I am having is the annotation positioning in a Google Charts Column Chart is not respecting 0 values in the data set and as such is not appearing outside the column as configured.

Instead it is appearing sometimes within the column (depending on its height) which is not the expected behavior and it looks like this:

[image: Incorrect Google Charts Graph]

You can see the `21` for `Cat B.` is starting from the bottom as is the `3` for `Cat D` instead of at the top like for `Cat A`.

I have the above example coded up here: http://jsfiddle.net/7x6Lxr3t/2/ where you can see the chart data is as follows:

```
var data = [
    ["Statuses", "Definition", "Dev", "Test", "Closed", {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
    ["Cat A.", 28, 25, 3, 7, 63],
    ["Cat B.", 3, 19, 0, 0, 21],
    ["Cat C.", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ["Cat D.", 0, 3, 0, 0, 3]
];
```

And the `annotations` is configured as follows:

```
    annotations: {
        alwaysOutside: true,
        textStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            bold: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    },
```

And I know it is the last 0 value before the annotation because if you change the `Cat B.` data to:

```
["Cat B.", 3, 19, 0, 1, 21],
```

The annotation is in the correct positioning:

[image: Corrected Cat. B Column]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.